# How to turn off ajax autoupdate in InputTextArea

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I want to get validation error in each input text, but there's problem in InputTextArea

```
                        <h:panelGrid columns="1" rendered="#{ownershipBacking.own.fgOwnershipStatus =='Tidak Aktif'}">      
                            <p:outputLabel value="Alasan *"></p:outputLabel> 
                            <p:inputTextarea id="alasanajax" cols="40" rows="5" minLength="1" required="true" counter="display" maxlength="200" autoResize="false" counterTemplate="{0} karakter tersisa" value="#{ownershipBacking.own.inactiveReason}" requiredMessage="#{MsgBundle['text.msgs.mst.province.title.reason.empty']}" validatorMessage="#{MsgBundle['text.msgs.mst.owner.reason']}">
                                <f:validateLength minimum="1" maximum="200"></f:validateLength>
                                <p:ajax update="alasanajax" event="keyup" />
                            </p:inputTextarea>
                            <p:message for="alasanajax" ></p:message>
                            <h:outputText id="display" styleClass="charremaining"></h:outputText>
                        </h:panelGrid>
```

Here's the error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NYyO.png) when i try to type 1 - 0 the ajax auto updating, so the result like 0 - 1, any help would be great :)

Comment: @Kukeltje that's the error when i try to type 1234567890 , the ajax auto updating so the outcome is 0987654321

Comment: You **yourself** explicitly update the component in the ajax call. Remove the update and you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

solved, so I just change the

> event="keyup"

into

event="blur"

Comment: Good change, but why do you update the component itself?

Comment: I want to validate each input text, so when they left the input text box blank, the validation error will pop out automatically without press submit button.

Comment: ow BalusC, i didn't know that, because in my other inputtext (not inputtextarea) it works fine.